# Сравнение строки

Tags: rust

Не выводит Yes при вводе  say.

```
use std::io;
fn main(){
     let mut key =String::new();
     io::stdin().read_line(&mut key).expect("Ошибка");
     if key=="say"{println!("Yes");}
     else{println!("No");}
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`read_line` не удаляет символы конца строки из прочитанной строки. Если пробельные символы в конце строки не важны, можно воспользоваться методом `trim_right`:

```
use std::io;
fn main(){
     let mut key =String::new();
     io::stdin().read_line(&mut key).expect("Ошибка");
     if key.trim_right() == "say" {
         println!("Yes");
     } else {
         println!("No");
     }
 }
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=0453aedadf81ba92b65a2c2a30e947fe&version=stable)